# What is the specific algorithm Postgres uses to truncate identifiers for foreign keys?

Tags: postgresql

I use/contribute to a Haskell library (Persistent) to generate migrations for Postgres. The library works by reading Haskell data types, then generates appropriate tables matching those types.

It does this by looking at what database schema is expected based off the Haskell types (i.e. a Haskell record named `Settings` implies a table should be created named `settings`), then comparing that to what's in Postgres (if there's no table named `settings`, it will perform a migration to create that table).

Unfortunately this doesn't work well when Postgres truncates identifiers, which it does at 63 characters as mentioned in the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Given some SQL like:

```
CREATE TABLE an_extremely_fantastically_super_long_name_child(an_extremely_fantastically_super_long_name_parent_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES an_extremely_fantastically_super_long_name_parent);

CREATE TABLE my_massively_huge_biggest_child_table (biggest_ever_column_name_that_will_reference_a_parent INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES an_extremely_fantastically_super_long_name_parent);
```

It will produce a foreign key constraint named `my_massively_huge_biggest_chi_biggest_ever_column_name_tha_fkey` (Removing a portion of the table name and a portion of the column name and adding `_fkey`).

I could make the Haskell library truncate all identifiers it wants to create to 63 characters, which would solve the problem. However, I would like to keep compatibility with what Postgres generates when you use the `REFERENCES` syntax. To do that, I need to copy the algorithm used in Postgres. What is this algorithm? I've tried to search for it in the Postgres source code, but as Postgres is a pretty massive project it's hard to find.

I think if I gave it enough sample data I could work out the exact formula, but it would be nice to just look at the source code, too.

Comment: This might be better asked on the sister site, http://DBA.StackExchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~postgresql/src/backend/commands/indexcmds.c`

after line #2000: `ChooseIndexName()` and friends.

[this is for indexes, but the method is similar for other generated names]